# block none is not working for li element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to block, hide `<li>` element based on some condition, So I tried like below code.

```js
if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "SLP State Head") {
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
} else if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "RRSOC Viewer") {
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName" value="RRSOC Viewer" />
<ul>
  <li id="addStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Add New Store</li>
  <li id="deleteStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Delete Store</li>
  <li class="" href="#" role="button" onclick="return DownloadAllStateReport();">Export Report</li>
  <li class="" role="button" onclick="return DownloadHelpManual();">Help Manual</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant select and CSS. You likely want an onchange of the select

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal: It's on the page,  and its inheriting `MasterPage`

Comment: @mplungjan: I am not using drop-down, so cant use `onchange`

Comment: So show what you are using. We do not want to guess!

Comment: what is ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName?

Comment: @mplungjan: I am using `ul` `li` and I want to show hide it on pageload with some condition..

Comment: @user3551009: Its a hidden field

Comment: @mplungjan: Updated it sir..

Comment: @mplungjan: What happening here is, its not hiding the `LI` elements.

Comment: It seems it works as expected. It shows addStore and hides deleteStore

Comment: @mplungjan: see now, updated it properly..

Comment: It seems to work as expected. They are now both hidden. You need to put the script AFTER the elements are rendered, e.g. before the </body> tag or in an onload function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this since I have commented a lot

Execute the script after the elements have loaded, by putting the script AFTER the elements OR wrap in an onload handler

The code can be simplified:

```js
var val   = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value;
var slp   = val = "SLP State Head";
var rrsoc = val = "RRSOC Viewer";
document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = rrsoc ? "none":"block";
document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = !slp && !rrsoc ? "block": "none";
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName" value="RRSOC Viewer" />
<ul>
  <li id="addStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Add New Store</li>
  <li id="deleteStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Delete Store</li>
  <li class="" href="#" role="button" onclick="return DownloadAllStateReport();">Export Report</li>
  <li class="" role="button" onclick="return DownloadHelpManual();">Help Manual</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked now..I dont know what was the actual issue, but with this code it worked. :) upvoted too

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executing after DOM loaded.
You need to bind change event for that select list for later actions.
Try following -

```js
foo();
document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName").onchange = function() {
  foo();
};

function foo() {
  if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "SLP State Head") {
    alert();
    document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
  } else if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "RRSOC Viewer") {
    document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName">
  <option value="SLP State Head">SLP State Head</option>
  <option value="RRSOC Viewer">RRSOC Viewer</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li id="addStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Add New Store</li>
  <li id="deleteStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Delete Store</li>
  <li class="" href="#" role="button" onclick="return DownloadAllStateReport();">Export Report</li>
  <li class="" role="button" onclick="return DownloadHelpManual();">Help Manual</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not using option, so cant use onchange function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your JS after body section or footer section. Here is demo I have created

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Hide li</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName" value="RRSOC Viewer" />
<ul>
  <li id="addStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Add New Store</li>
  <li id="deleteStore" class="" href="#" role="button">Delete Store</li>
  <li class="" href="#" role="button" >Export Report</li>
  <li class="" role="button" >Help Manual</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value);
if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "RRSOC Viewer") {
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
} else if (document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_hndSubGroupName').value == "Something value") { // same as above
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById('addStore').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('deleteStore').style.display = "block";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:

Please follow standards while coding, like all document elements can be defined at beginning in variable and use that at all places, instead of repeating everywhere.

Comment: @MrLister Previously at beginning 1st and 2nd conditions were same when posted, User has modified question

Comment: There was a brief moment where indeed the strings were the same. A few minutes